# How to use a PBR Material’s Mask Image

Tags: texturing, materials, masking

I downloaded a texture from https://cc0textures.com/view?tex=Marble03 which includes a mask.jpg file.

How do I integrate that new file into a node map? Here is my current node map.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Masks are used to mix other things. Mask is usually a grayscale image that controls how much of one thing you can see through another. You can use masks to mix different textures, colors, shaders and you can even mask effects you apply to something with them so it's really hard to tell what this was originally supposed to be used for. You could try to see what feature it matches on the material and see if it might be useful to you for anything, but it may also be that it is included by mistake and is not needed for anything in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

When using textures as masks (image or procedural) you need to plug the fac output of the texture you use as a mask into the fac output of what you want to mix.

The question is if you know what the map does?

Comment: It is usually some node's input that you plug some other node's output to and image textures do not have Fac output...

Comment: Sorry, my bad...